# SWI-Prolog - Listing entire knowledge base to file

Tags: file, prolog, export

I have a Prolog file where I'm consulting a knowledge base and adding my own predicates. I want to have a predicate that saves the entire updated knowledge base to a text file.

I've tried doing this with `listing/0`, but it seems I can't change its output stream. I could, technically, write each clause separately to the file with `portray_clause/2`, but I'd like to achieve this in a more elegant way.

Is there a predicate/predicate combination that will allow me to do this?

**EDIT:** I managed to output the entire knowledge base to a file like so:

```
tell('newkb.txt'), listing, told.
```

This achieves what I wanted to do, with a slight drawback: the new `newkb.txt` file contains a few automatically generated clauses that I'd rather not keep, if possible.

If this is the only/best solution, so be it. But, if there's a way to export the knowledge base, and *only* the knowledge base, I'd really like to hear it.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you aim to do. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have a Prolog file, let's call it `Project.pl`. Inside it I have: `:- ['knowledgebase.txt'].` `predicate_1(...) :- ... .` `predicate_2(...) :- ... .`, etc. I want to write a predicate that will output both the knowledge base that is being consulted and the predicates I've written in the `Project.pl` file to another file. Actually, though I've been looking for a solution for almost an hour, as soon as I posted this question, I managed to do (almost exactly) this in the following way: `tell('newkb.txt'), listing, told.`. This does add a lot of other generated predicates, however.

Comment: If this is the only/best way of achieving what I want, I'm happy, it works. But I'd rather do it in a way that only saves the original information and doesn't add any automatically generated predicates (such as `prolog_file_type/2`), if at all possible. For now, I'll edit the original question to add this information.

Comment: You should edit your question and add all that information there rather than in the comments. Meanwhile... How many predicates are in your knowledge base? If not too many, you could list them separately: `tell('newkb.txt'), listing(pred1), listing(pred2), ..., listing(pred-n), told.`

Comment: @lurker Get ready to be chastised for using Edinburg I/O instead of ISO... :)

Comment: The stuff SWI includes is weird. Interestingly, GNU does not include a bunch of weird stuff by default.

Comment: @DanielLyons haha well I was just following the OP's lead on that one. And I agree about SWI including weird (extraneous) stuff that doesn't belong to the user when doing a listing. Maybe they need to provide a `listing_of_just_my_stuff` predicate.

Comment: @lurker I edited my question right after posting the comments :) I know I can write the predicates/clauses one by one, but I was trying to avoid that. Not only do I find that an inelegant solution, this is part of an assignment, and I'm sure my professor wouldn't like it either. Thank you for the suggestion, though! Since I've found a way that (even if not exactly how I wanted it to work) works, I'll stick with that if I can't find another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`listing/0` lists the knowledge base (well, by default from the global `user` module.  There are several *hooks* in the `user` module that obscure this somehow.  Some are there by de-facto Prolog practice and some are SWI-prolog extensions.  They could of course be omitted from the listing, but that violates the most important use case of `listing/0`: find what is in the knowledge base and may thus lead to confusion in its own right.

You could switch to another module using e.g. (`empty` is just a name)

```
?- module(empty).
```

Now `listing/0` will work as you expect.

It is not very clear how to other facts and rules come in the knowledge base.  If you just add them by hand, it might be easier to edit the file and run `?- make.` to reload the file.  If they are updated using assert/retract, you either need a module as above or some way to enumerate the parts you want saved.